# $(this) doesnt work with javascript created elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't find out why my script can't work. Here is simple table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>Paul Stevenson</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <td>28. 09. 1978</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My script adds link to th elements.

```
var toolbar = $("<div />");
var link = $("<a />").attr({"target" : "_blank"});
toolbar.append( gmaps );
```

When user moves cursor to th element, it shows the toolbar.

```
$('th').on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {
      if (e.type === 'mouseenter') { $(this).append( toolbar ); }
      else { $(this).find( $("div") ).remove() }
  });
```

Why my variable

```
var thisNext = $(this).parent().next().text();
```

Does not get the td text and do not add it to link?

You can see [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bZWBkB?editors=0010) as well

Comment: What exactly you wanna do?

Comment: `var thisNext = ...` is not inside of an event handler. `this` is `Window` where you have it written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do $(this) inside the function

```
$('th').on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {
```

then the $(this) is pointing to the **th** element but when you are accessing the $(this) to get the text

```
var thisNext = $(this).parent().next().text();
```

it is outside the function and here $(this) points to the window object.

if you need to select the text using the proper selector here. check more here http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp

this is the updated code for what you are trying to achieve.

```
$('th').on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {

  if (e.type === 'mouseenter') { 

    var toolbar = $("<div />").css({
      "padding": "5px",
      "background" : "#F8F8F8",
      "position" : "absolute",
      "borderRadius" : "5px 0 5px 5px",
      "left" : "-30px",
      "top" : "0",
      "zIndex" : "99"
    });

    var link = $("<a />").css({
        "display" : "block",
        "height" : "20px",
        "width" : "20px",
        "marginBottom" : "5px",
        "background-size" : "100%",
        "position" : "relative"}).attr({
          "target" : "_blank"
    });
    var thisNext = $($(this).parent().children('td')[0]).text();
    var gmaps = link.clone().css({"background" : "red"}).attr({
        href: 'https://www.google.cz/search?q=' + thisNext });
    toolbar.append( gmaps );
    $(this).append( toolbar ); }
    else 
    { 
      $(this).children('div').remove();
    }
  });
```

codepen: http://codepen.io/deep2701/pen/YWVkkA?editors=0010#anon-signup

Hope this will help you.

Comment: So I should make this?  

$('th').on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {
      
      var thisNext = $(this).parent().next().text();
  
      if (e.type === 'mouseenter') { $(this).append( toolbar ); }
      else { $(this).find( $("div") ).remove() }
  });

Toolbar do not append then.

Comment: check the updated answer above i have  made few changes to your function. hope this will work fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

You're attempting to use `this` outside of a handler - so `this` is not set to what you think it is. Inside `$('th').on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) {` `this` refers to the `th` being acted on - in your example, you're just trying to access `this` and assume it refers to what you want.

Comment: So I should make this? $('th').on("mouseenter mouseleave", function(e) { var thisNext = $(this).parent().next().text(); if (e.type === 'mouseenter') { $(this).append( toolbar ); } else { $(this).find( $("div") ).remove() } }); Toolbar do not append then.